# Moscow ML pattern matching

Tags: ml

I am trying to check, if all products on list are above limits

```
fun search([], _) = true 
  | search(x1::xs, limit) = #2(#1 x1) > limit andalso search(xs, limit)`
```

and I receive unresolve record pattern. Whats wrong with my function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your function is most likely your use of `#1` and `#2` which are used to extract the first and second component, respectively from a given tuple. This is supposed to work for *any* tuple, i.e., pair, triple, quadruple, etc. E.g.,

```
> #1 (1, 2);
val it = 1: int
```

and

```
> #1 ("a", "b", "c", "d");
val it = "a": string
```

In your function the compiler (or interpreter) can't figure out how many components the tuple `x1` is supposed to have.

You can help by giving an explicit type annotation like

```
fun search ([], _) = true
  | search ((x:(int*int)*int)::xs, l) = #2 (#1 x) > l andalso search (xs, l);
```

or (probably better) explicitly take apart the tuple `x` inside the pattern

```
fun search ([], _) = true
  | search (((_, x), _)::xs, l) = x > l andalso search (xs, l);
```